# Spark: Convert hex string to Decimal

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to convert an md5 hash column into a number column in Spark?

Tried converting to Decimal directly. Also tried using conv. But neigher work (please, see below).
Strange enough conv converts different hashes to same value.

```
(1 to 5).toDF("id")
.withColumn("md5_id", md5($"id".cast("string")))
.withColumn("conv_id", conv($"md5_id", 16, 10))
.withColumn("num_id", $"md5_id".cast(DecimalType(38,0)))
.show(false)

+---+--------------------------------+--------------------+-------+
|id |md5_id                          |conv_id             |num_id|
+---+--------------------------------+--------------------+-------+
|1  |c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b|18446744073709551615|null   |
|2  |c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|18446744073709551615|null   |
|3  |eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3|18446744073709551615|null   |
|4  |a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c|18446744073709551615|null   |
|5  |e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5|18446744073709551615|null   |
+---+--------------------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

**UPDATE**

In case someone else bumps into the same problem, this worked for my needs:

```
    def toNum = udf((hex: String) =>
      new java.math.BigInteger(hex.toUpperCase, 16)
    )

    (1 to 5).toDF("id")
      .withColumn("hashed_id", toNum(substring(md5($"id".cast("string")), 0, 31)))
      .show(false)

+---+--------------------------------------+
|id |hashed_id                             |
+---+--------------------------------------+
|1  |16348679641551244288068877217848318025|
|2  |16625230717330387431313232838613092450|
|3  |19672244359719724500030062827806555055|
|4  |13998420256418836516930895031794147618|
|5  |19012319408524223020738990858985681293|
+---+--------------------------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- hashed_id: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this case is complicated and I will tell why. Converting MD5 to a number usually create a `BigInteger`. Let me show how it can be done without Spark:

```
scala> val hex = "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3"
scala> new java.math.BigInteger(hex.toUpperCase, 16)
res28: java.math.BigInteger = 314755909755515592000481005244904880883
```

So as you can see the number is HUGE, actually is larger than the Decimal you want to convert of 38, and this number is 39 digits. And this is not supported by Spark with the default data types conversion. So, a way to solve that is using the Decimal Library with a udf, but you will loose some precision of the data. So here is how you can do this:

```
def md5toIntString = udf((hex: String) =>
    Decimal(new java.math.BigInteger(hex.toUpperCase, 16)).toString
)
(1 to 5).toDF("id")
.withColumn("md5_id", md5($"id".cast("string")))
.withColumn("conv_id", conv($"md5_id", 16, 10))
.withColumn("num_id", md5toIntString($"md5_id"))
.show(false)
```

And you will be able to see the result as:

```
+---+--------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+
|id |md5_id                          |conv_id             |num_id                                 |
+---+--------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+
|1  |c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b|18446744073709551615|261578874264819908609102035485573088411|
|2  |c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|18446744073709551615|266003691477286198901011725417809479212|
|3  |eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3|18446744073709551615|314755909755515592000481005244904880883|
|4  |a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c|18446744073709551615|223974724102701384270894320508706361900|
|5  |e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5|18446744073709551615|304197110536387568331823853743770900693|
+---+--------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

So that is why you are facing this issue, the size of the md5 data is between `1 and len(2^128-1)` that is around 39 digits.

So I suggest or to use as string, or convert it to another type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That´s great info. I´ve been trying to overcome limitation of "conv" while doing the conversion. And the udf does the trick. md5 has been used as an example of something big enough that conv couldn´t handle. Thanks once again